# Android show notification from app

Tags: android, notifications, alarms

I have application that needs to show notification in status bar.
I have to set time and date in my app, and on that time and date notification needs to be shown in status bar as somekind of reminder.

I've tried this tutorial, but scheduled event isn't triggered at all.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What tutorial? What's the problem with the provided example?

Comment: Maybe add some code? It's not even clear whether you have a problem with the scheduling or with displaying the notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) in connection with a SQL database to handle notifications. You could use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule alarms which are fetched from your database. You should use a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to add alarms when the phone boots in order to handle the situation where the phone is rebooted by the user or system failure.

This [howto](http://smartandroidians.blogspot.dk/2010/04/alarmmanager-and-notification-in.html) explains how to use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).